# coredata how to populate a entity attribute with fixed number of values

Tags: core-data, swift3

I want to measure readings from a process at 15 minute intervals and update an entity.
I want to have attribute uniqueId(apart from many other attributes in that entity which store measured readings) to have 96 rows where each row's uniqueId attribute is populated with numbers 1 through 96 to represent a day. I want to populate the uniqueId values initially only once so later I can update the corresponding rows with measured readings.
How can I get the initial values populated?

Comment: Why create them in advance if you won't have any data for them?

Comment: Because I want to use it as rolling log and update everyday. The 96 entries will always be there and the I just need to udpate the right row at the right interval